# Regex form to get each person's points as a JS object

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have this string:

`Phantom_FR - 5 Points\n\nmineblox17,Dominus_Loading - 0 Points\n\ndavidroks528,beeks567,JohnDoe54631 - 4 Points\n\n\n\n **PLEASE ARCHIVE THIS CARD WHEN YOU ARE FINISHED WITH IT**`,

I need it to return something like:

```
{"5":["Phantom_FR], "0":[mineblox17, Dominus_Loading]}
```

...and so on. I cant seem to figure it out.

It is encoded to this format in another language so that wouldn't help. How can I extract the information I need?

Comment: Got bored of it but still usable maybe. https://regex101.com/r/8ouNpf/6

Comment: Yeah it helps a lot but it only shows one for each point, instead of all the people.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: I haven't tried anything but what Eraklon gave me, It didn't take into account all of the people with the points, I expected what was in the question, the expression used in the link commented by Eraklon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `/([^\n][\w,]+) - (\d+) Points/g` seems sufficient for your use case. This places the comma-delimited list of usernames in the first group and the points in the second group.

Note that it's assumed that the points are pre-grouped and there will be no clashes between them otherwise a key would be overwritten. It also assumes that each username group is preceded by a newline or beginning of string.

Browser JS:

```js
const s = "Phantom_FR - 5 Points\n\nmineblox17,Dominus_Loading - 0 Points\n\ndavidroks528,beeks567,JohnDoe54631 - 4 Points\n\n\n\n **PLEASE ARCHIVE THIS CARD WHEN YOU ARE FINISHED WITH IT**";

const pattern = /([^\n][\w,]+) - (\d+) Points/g;
const usersByPoints = Object.fromEntries([...s.matchAll(pattern)]
  .map(([, users, points]) => [points, users.split(",")]));
console.log(usersByPoints);
```

NodeJS:

```js
const s = "Phantom_FR - 5 Points\n\nmineblox17,Dominus_Loading - 0 Points\n\ndavidroks528,beeks567,JohnDoe54631 - 4 Points\n\n\n\n **PLEASE ARCHIVE THIS CARD WHEN YOU ARE FINISHED WITH IT**";

const pattern = /([^\n][\w,]+) - (\d+) Points/g;
const usersByPoints = {};

for (let m; m = pattern.exec(s); usersByPoints[m[2]] = m[1].split(","));

console.log(usersByPoints);
```

Comment: what is ... in front of s?

Comment: [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). `[...]` lets me extract an array of matches out of the `RegExpStringIterator` object that `matchAll` returns.

Comment: it also says .fromEntries is not a function and .matchAll could not be found

Comment: Are you using Node? If so, which version?

Comment: i am using version 10.x

Comment: version v10.15.3

Comment: Cool, I will update shortly. I assumed browser JS here.